# Difference between debian and ubuntugis repositories?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I just spent some time struggling to upgrade to QGIS 2.18.

I originally had these lines in my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntugis xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main
```

but when I tried to install I was getting error messages like:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    python-qgis : Depends: libqgis-analysis2.18.14 but it is not going to be installed
>                  Depends: libqgis-server2.18.14 but it is not going to be installed

...etc.

When I changed the sources.list entries to the following the problem was fixed:

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian xenial main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian xenial main
```

My question is, why?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libqgis-analysis2.18.14` to see why that is not going to be installed, same for the others. Debian is compiled against the main ubuntu repo, so no unmet dependencies there. Make sure to add the pgpkey for the ubuntugis ppa and qgis repo.